# Drupal 6.22 - Colorbox plugin missing

Tags: files

I can't seem to get the [colorbox plugin](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) (colorbox-6.x-1.0) working with my Drupal 6.22 site. I'm currently working on Ubuntu Natty, and this is the folder structure for how I have the plugin and module setup:

```
 - sites
    - all
       - libraries
          - colorbox
             - colorbox
                - jquery.colorbox-min.js
                - jquery.colorbox.js
             - [other folders: content, examp1, examp2, examp3, examp4, examp5]
    - default
       - modules
          - colorbox
             - colorbox.module
             - etc, etc
```

Other stuff I already have done:

- [jQuery Update plugin](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) installed
- set permissions on `sites/all/libraries` folder using `chmod a+w ~/public_html/drup_test/sites/all/libraries`
- flushed all caches

I'm still after all of this getting the "*You need to download the Colorbox plugin and extract the entire contents of the archive into the sites/all/libraries/colorbox folder of your server*" error. Please could someone help me as I don't know what else could be the problem.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT: SOLVED!!**

With iStryker's help, I realised that there was some weird permission setting on the `/sites/all` folder. Whilst I haven't sorted out the permission issue on that folder, this alternative worked (if this has also happened to you)...under `/sites/default/` create a folder called `libraries` and put your jQuery plugins there. Then in *Drupal Admin > Administer by Module > Colorbox > Colorbox Plugin Settings*, change the plugin path to `/sites/default/libraries/colorbox`. Not the grandest solution, but it works!  Note that this also worked for the ShadowBox module and plugin.

Comment: Any errors on admin/settings/colorbox page?

Comment: yes, the same message above "*You need to download the Colorbox plugin and extract the entire contents of the archive into the sites/all/libraries/colorbox folder of your server*". I really don't get what could be the issue...all files are where they should be according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised:

Your directory structure is correct.  Your file directory permissions are not.  Your `chmod a+w` command gives read and write permissions.  In your case, to get rid error message you must have read and execute permission on the /sites/all/libraries/colorbox & /sites/all/libraries/colorbox/colorbox directories and read permissions on the 2 javascript files.   Colorbox.module does a file_exist call

`if (file_exists($library_path .'/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js') && file_exists($library_path .'/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js')) {`

Depending on your operating system, and setting, PHP's file_exists() function is handle differently.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, that doesn't work either

Comment: I'm working on ubuntu linux...d you think it could be a permission issue?

Comment: depends,   You files do look right.   remember to recursively change all the files in the libraries directory

Comment: my answer has been revised, please ignore Shalan first comment.

Comment: ok, let me try your suggestions

Comment: so do you think `chmod 777` will suffice?

Comment: depending how your directory is setup 755 or 775

Comment: i don't get it!!! none of those worked

Comment: @Shalan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/891/discussion-between-istryker-and-shalan)